# How can I alter this code to make the countdown not reset on reload?

Tags: javascript

I got this code from [here](http://www.codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=149460). However, I am not too great with JS and need a little help getting the timer to not reset on reload. Also, I want it to countdown days instead of hours, minutes, and seconds. Can somebody please help me out?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>
  <title></title>
<script>
/*<![CDATA[*/

function zxcCountDown(id,mess,secs,mins,hrs,days){
 var obj=document.getElementById(id);
 var oop=obj.oop
 if (!oop){
  obj.oop=new zxcCountDownOOP(obj);
 }
 obj.oop.start(mess,secs,mins,hrs,days);
}

function zxcCountDownOOP(obj,mess){
 this.obj=obj;
 this.to=null;
}

zxcCountDownOOP.prototype={

 start:function(mess,secs,mins,hrs,days){
  clearTimeout(this.to);
  this.mess=mess;
  this.mhd=[mins,hrs,days];
  var date=new Date();
  this.fin=new Date(date.getFullYear(),date.getMonth(),date.getDate()+(days||0),date.getHours()+(hrs||0),date.getMinutes()+(mins||0),date.getSeconds()+(secs||0));
  this.cng();
 },

 cng:function(){
  var now=new Date(),s=(this.fin-now)/1000+1,d=Math.floor(s/60/60/24),h=Math.floor(s/60/60-d*24),m=Math.floor(s/60-h*60-d*24*60),s=Math.floor(s-m*60-h*3600-d*24*60*60);
  if (this.fin-now>-500){
   this.obj.innerHTML=(this.mhd[2]?(d>9?d:'0'+d)+' days ':'')+(this.mhd[1]||this.mhd[2]?(h>9?h:'0'+h)+' hours ':'')+(this.mhd[0]||this.mhd[1]||this.mhd[2]?(m>9?m:'0'+m)+' minutes ':'')+(s>9?s:'0'+s)+' seconds';
   this.to=setTimeout(function(oop){ return function(){ oop.cng(); }}(this),1000);
  }
  else if (this.mess){
   this.obj.innerHTML=this.mess;
  }
 }

}

/*]]>*/
</script></head>

<body onload="zxcCountDown('tst','message',20); zxcCountDown('tst1','message 1',0,0,2,0);">

<span id="tst" ></span> <input type="button" name="" value="Re-Start" onmouseup="zxcCountDown('tst','message',20);"/>
<br />
<span id="tst1" ></span>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, you can't. Javascript does not maintain state on load. There are several options, though.

1. You could use local storage to save the current count and retrieve
   it again on page load. This is a newer API, though, and won't be backwards compatible.
   http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html
2. You could store the value in a cookie and retrieve the cookie upon reloading the page.
   http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html

That's about it, though.

Comment: Another (less elegant) way to store the count would be in the anchor part of the URL, e.g. http://example.com/countdown.html#14214

Comment: That's only if the page load is caused by a click. If you press the refresh button, javascript won't use the newly edited URL.

Answer (score 0):

javascript is a client side script. And it does reloads each time the page is reloaded. To persist the variables, you will need to look into something outside the script.

Did you try to use cookies ?They can save your variable values for as long as you want.

Just fetch the value from cookies at each reload

Comment: yeah.. unless you want to save the values in session and fetch them on each reload, cookies rock !! Best option for local values on client side